# Json query - could not get results from array

Tags: json

I just making small code for tracking app to my website.

I'm pretty new at json so I could not find out what is wrong at my code. It's been two days now:

Here is the code

```
 <http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js>  
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
      var inputField = $('#tracking');
      var outputElement = $('#textResult');
      inputField.keyup(function() {
       if (inputField.val().length > 1) {
        $.getJSON('http://sporing.bring.no/sporing.json?q=' + inputField.val(),                       
             function(data){ 
             outputElement.html('ID' + data.consignmentSet.consignmentId);
             });

       } else {
           outputElement.html('No result!');
       }
      });
     });
    </script>


<div>                                                                      
<input type="text" id="tracking" style="width: 17;" maxlength="30"/><br/><span      id="textResult"></span>
</div>
</body></html>
```

My source is: http://developer.bring.com/api/trackingapi.html#json

Tracking json source: http://sporing.bring.no/sporing.json?q=TESTPACKAGE-AT-PICKUPPOINT

Links gives result, but i'n not able to display it.

It is simple code, so hopefully someone can explain me what I'm doing wrong...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

data.consignmentSet contains an array with one element so

```
data.consignmentSet[0].consignmentId
```

should work!

You can use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate and pretty print your JSON to better dig into it's structure.

Also, you could use a debugger to explore the content of the *data* at runtime. Most browsers have their *F12 developer tools* or you could install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). Then switch to the *Script* tab, go to the line in code where you access the data and click on the line number. A breakpoint will be set where code execution will stop when running the script. When the breakpoint is reached, you can explore the data in the *Watch* window.

Comment: That was it, now it works. I also needed to add &callback=? in the end of query string to get it working. Thanks might!